# How do I mount .vhd file?

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I'm using 13.04 Raring amd64 and **I need to mount a .vhd file on my ubuntu**. I've googled about it and found that virtualbox-fuse package is the answer.

But the package was deleted from apt repository. Is there any way to install the package w/ 13.04? or is there any alternative to virtualbox-fuse?

Comment: I just did this same thing, and my search results ended in that you could convert the vdi to a raw image

Comment: boo. that is not a good solution when a vhd or vdi file can be way too large to make a duplicate of as a raw image

Comment: So, if i install virtualbox i can use vdfuse command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did for it:

It seems not there's a smooth way to go. I just downloaded `virtualbox-fuse` deb package file from launchpad. ([here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/virtualbox-fuse))

I picked 4.1.18 because my vbox is a little bit older but I guess it would works with recent version.

Install the package with `dpkg -i`. You may need to specify `--force-depends` option for installing.

Comment: Then what? How do you mount a VHD after installing that?

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-fuse
sudo mkdir /mnt/vhd-disk/
sudo vdfuse -f disk.vhd /mnt/vhd-disk/
sudo mount -o loop  /mnt/vhd-disk/Partition1 /mnt/partition1
```

Note that you may need additional options to `mount` to set permissions to your liking.

Comment: It works, you can download vdfuse from http://vdfuse.sourceforge.net/  for example in my case the last line was:
     sudo mount -o -loop /tmp/win/Partition1  /mnt/Windows

Answer (score 4):

Using Ubuntu 15.10 (works also on Ubuntu 16.04), you can install vhdimount and tsk (The Sleuth Kit) via:

```
sudo apt-get install libvhdi-utils sleuthkit
```

Then you can proceed as follows:

```
sudo mkdir -v /mnt/vhd
sudo vhdimount -X allow_root /path/to/file.vhd /mnt/vhd/
sudo mmls -aB /mnt/vhd/vhdi1
```

Next, you'll have to calculate the offset from the output of `mmls` like this:

```
echo offset*512 | bc
```

And to finish:

```
sudo mkdir -v /media/${USER}/your/folder
sudo mount -vt ntfs-3g -o ro,noload,offset=offset-found /mnt/vhd/vhdi1 /media/${USER}/your/folder
```

Replace `offset-found` by your offset. You may also have to change the fs-type according to the fs-type included in your vhd file.

I've made a script so I don't have to type this every time ;)

Comment: This mounts it as read only. What can I do to mount it with write permissions? Omitting the `ro` for `mount` still results in read only.

Comment: Change `ro` by `rw` and that should run in read/write instead of read/only. `vhdimount` maps to `/mnt/vhd/vhdi1` in read/write mode but the next command using `mount` is in read/only if you don't specify `rw` as an option

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04: Instead of using mmls or fdisk to find out about the starting sector of the partition, you can also use `kpartx` to create a virtual device file that you can mount without an `offset` option: `sudo kpartx -av /mnt/vhd/vhdi1; sudo mount -vt ntfs-3g -o ro,noload /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /media/${USER}/your/folder`

Answer (score 2):

Searching Ubuntu's Launchpad space, the following comes up:

> virtualbox (The binary 'virtualbox-fuse' is part of the virtualbox package)

This means that they merged `virtualbox-fuse` into the main package and you just need to install virtualbox from the repository (This is what used to be called `virtualbox-ose`, so if you need the PUEL licensed "full" version, this won't help you.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer not to rely on a VM to access data on a vhd image.  Since `virtualbox-fuse` and `vdfuse` is no longer available in Ubuntu ([not since precise (12.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox-fuse&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)) and Debian ([not since Wheezy (7)](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=virtualbox)).  I was able to mount the NTFS partition of a personal VHD using `blk-tap`.

Insert the apropriate pid from `tap-ctl spawn`, of course.  Your partitioning scheme may be different from mine, so adjust accordingly.

```
# apt-get install blktap-utils
# modprobe blktap
# tap-ctl allocate
/dev/xen/blktap-2/tapdev0
# tap-ctl spawn
tapdisk spawned with pid 1234
# tap-ctl attach -m 0 -p 1234
# tap-ctl open -m 0 -p 1234 -a vhd:/full/path/to/image.vhd
# mount /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-tapdev0p1
# ls -lh do/your/thing with/all/your/files.txt 
# tap-ctl close -m 0 -p 1234
# tap-ctl detach -m 0 -p 1234
# tap-ctl free -m 0
```

These steps came from the xen project's [wiki](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Blktap).

My block device was created at `/dev/xen/blktap-2/blktap0`.  For some reason, `kpartx -a` would not map partitions (I was looking for /dev/xen/blktap-2/tapdev0p1), but I found that `/dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-tapdev0p1` had been linked to the block device for the partition.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully mounted a .vhdx file I made with Windows 10 Backup files to my Ubuntu 16.04 OS using a program called `guestmount`

[`guestmount` manual page on libguestfs.org](http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html).

Note that permissions will need to be adjusted, or mount accessed after `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` has been executed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use VirtualBox.

> VirtualBox is a free x86 virtualization solution allowing a wide range
>   of x86 operating systems such as Windows, DOS, BSD or Linux to run on
>   a Linux system.

To install VirtualBox Under Ubuntu 13.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Once it finishes installing, go ahead and create a new virtual machine

[image]

Type in the name.  **Make sure that you choose the correct type, and version of the OS that is in the VHD.**

[image]

Choose use an existing virtual hard drive file, and browse for your VHD file, and then click on create.

[image]

Comment: That will let you run the OS that is on the VHD, but it does not allow you to mount the image in Linux.