# Recovering files from a windows 10 Backup on Ubuntu

Tags: files, data-recovery

I have recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. Before that, I made a full backup, expecting to restore some files inside Ubuntu. Now I'm stuck with a bunch of .vhdx files and a headache. How do I proceed?

I have already tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819474/how-can-i-attach-a-vhdx-or-vhd-file-in-linux/37790474 and failed with the following error message:

```
guestmount: no operating system was found on this disk
```

Comment: Possibly related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819474/how-can-i-attach-a-vhdx-or-vhd-file-in-linux/37790474

Comment: Tried it already. It didn't work. Guestmount can't seem to find an operating system

Comment: Anything you have already tried please add that to your question so that we are not doubling up things that you have done. Also, please add any error messages that you are receiving.  The more details the better!  It helps us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/295155/how-do-i-mount-vhd-file