# How can I access WSL2 files from a dual-boot Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, files, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows and Ubuntu dual-booted as well as having WSL2 installed on Windows.

I am unable to boot into Windows, however I can boot into Ubuntu. Therefore I need to copy my Windows files to the Ubuntu drive and reinstall Windows.

I have managed to do this for my regular windows files, but I need to copy files that I had in WSL2 on Windows. I can't find the location - I have checked
`/Windows/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited`, but none of my files are here

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The files for WSL2 distributions are stored in a virtual drive named `ext4.vhdx`.  Typically, that's going to be under something *like* (but not exactly):

```
C:\Windows\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu...
```

The exact folder will vary based on the version of Ubuntu originally installed from the Microsoft Store.

However, it's also possible for it to be placed elsewhere on the drive.

I would recommend searching the Windows drive for `ext4.vhdx`.

Assuming you have enough space, you'll probably just want to copy this file in its entirety.

If you do want to access the files inside it directly from within Ubuntu, I would start with [How do I mount .vhd file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/295155/1165986), although it appears that's a quite-old question with some outdated answers.  It's not something I've done myself, so I can't help you with that part of it.

I would recommend (again, space permitting) creating a backup of the `ext4.vhdx` file before using any tools on it.